# Retrieving objects from Parse iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am new to programming and am trying to develop an iOS app using Swift. However, I ran into a problem trying to retrieve previously saved information from Parse to use in my app.

To save the information I use the following code:

```
    var user = PFUser.currentUser()

    var number = self.phoneNumber.text as String
    var insta = self.instagramUsername.text as String
    var snapp = self.snapchatName.text as String
    var twitter = self.twitterHandle.text as String
    var bio = self.profileBio.text as String

    var socialData = PFObject(className: "socialData")

    socialData["phoneNumber"] = number
    socialData["instagram"] = insta
    socialData["snapchat"] = snapp
    socialData["twitter"] = twitter
    socialData["bio"] = bio
    socialData["user"] = user

    socialData.save()
```

This saves the information on Parse correctly but then when I try to retrieve the Instagram name or anything else specifically using a query I get an error. Here is how I have been trying to retrieve it:

```
    var user = PFUser.currentUser()

    var query = PFQuery(className:"socialData")
    query.whereKey("user", equalTo: user)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.

            // Do something with the found objects

            var socialData = PFObject(className: "socialData")


            let instaUsername = socialData["instagram"] as String

            println(instaUsername)


        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)
        }
    }
```

The logs say fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. After the app crashes. Yet, the information is correctly displayed on Parse. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: inside the closure you are creating a new (empty) `socialData` object - you should retrieve the object from the `objects` array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove this line within your `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` block entirely:

```
var socialData = PFObject(className: "socialData")
```

and replace this line:

```
let instaUsername = socialData["instagram"] as String
```

with this:

```
let instaUsername = objects[0]["instagram"] as String
```

so you're actually utilizing the object array retrieved from the query, accessing the first object which matches the current user, then getting the "instagram" key's stored value from that PFObject dictionary.